# How could I keep var/lib/snaped/snaps folder smallest?

Tags: snap

I found there are so many old versions copies.
Could I use some configure to limited only store the last version copies?

Comment: Possible:  https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps